# hline does not show up in the output

Tags: longtable, supertabular, hhline, hline

I have some long and large Microsoft word tables that I have to fit in my LaTeX document. I converted them with the Libreoffice extension, and it was easy enough. The most difficult part will be to fit them in my `scrbook` document, but right now I am puzzled with a problem that is apparently simple: the bottom line of some of the table does not show on the output. I will attach here a short sample of the code. This table is rotated (with `minipage`), but even in the non-rotated table the line does not show.The ///hline command looks ok to me, and I even compared to the table that do not have the same problem. I do not understand.

Also, I know that `supertabular` is often replaced my `longtable` bou I have never used either of them; so, suggestions about cleaning and improving this code are more than welcome

```
% This file was converted to LaTeX by Writer2LaTeX ver. 1.6.1
% see http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net for more info
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=, pdfauthor=, pdfsubject=, pdfkeywords=}
% Text styles
\newcommand\textstyleEmphasis[1]{\textit{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother
% Page layout (geometry)
\setlength\voffset{-1in}
\setlength\hoffset{-1in}
\setlength\topmargin{2cm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{2cm}
\setlength\textheight{17.001cm}
\setlength\textwidth{25.7cm}
\setlength\footskip{0.0cm}
\setlength\headheight{0cm}
\setlength\headsep{0cm}
% Footnote rule
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.119cm}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-0.018cm}\setlength\leftskip{0pt}\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}\noindent\textcolor{black}{\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.018cm}}\vspace*{0.101cm}}
% Pages styles
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ps@Standard{
  \renewcommand\@oddhead{}
  \renewcommand\@evenhead{}
  \renewcommand\@oddfoot{}
  \renewcommand\@evenfoot{}
  \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{Standard}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{2022-01-01}
\begin{document}
\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}\pagestyle{Standard}

\bigskip

\rotatebox{90}{%
    \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\tablefirsthead{}
\tablehead{}
\tabletail{}
\tablelasttail{}
\begin{supertabular}{|m{3.6139998cm}|m{7.1060004cm}|m{7.0880003cm}m{7.09cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|m{25.498001cm}|}{\textbf{Studio:} Forbes SS \textit{et al.} Meta-analysis of randomized controlled
trials comparing open and laparoscopic ventral and incisional hernia repair with mesh. British Journal of Surgery
2009.}\\\hline
\textbf{Disegno dello studio}

 \textbf{Livello di evidenza} &
\textbf{Dettagli dello studio/limitazione} &
\multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{\textbf{Caratteristiche dei pazienti}} &
\textbf{Interventi}\\\hline
\textbf{Disegno dello studio:}

Systematic review e meta-analisi di RCTs

~

\textbf{Certezza delle prove:}

Bassa

~
 &
\textbf{Paesi:} Non applicabile

\textbf{Centri:} Non applicabile

\textbf{Setting: }Ernie ventrali primitive e incisionali

\textbf{Finanziamento}: Non riportato

\textbf{Tasso di dropout: }Non applicabile

\textbf{Limitazioni}:

\textbf{Critical appraisal: }AMSTAR II

~
 &
\multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{Pazienti con ernia ventrale primaria o ernia incisionale

~

\textbf{Ricerca bibliografica: }Gennaio 1950 -- Gennaio 2009

~

\textbf{Criteri di inclusione: }Studi prospettici randomizzati comparanti la tecnica laparoscopica con quella open,
entrambe con l'utilizzo di protesi

~

\textbf{Criteri di esclusione:} Studi focalizzati sulla riparazione di ernie inguinali, interventi senza protesi} &
Tecnica di riparazione laparoscopica vs. a cielo aperto con utilizzo di protesi\\\hline
\textbf{Note}: &
\multicolumn{3}{m{21.683998cm}|}{\textbf{Studi inclusi:} Asencio 2008, Barbaros 2007, Carbajo 1999, Misra 2006,
Moreno-Egea 2002, Navarra 2007, Olmi 2007, Pring 2008}\\\hline
\textbf{Outcomes} &
{}- Recidiva erniaria

{}- Durata dell'intervento chirurgico

{}- Durata dell'ospedalizzazione

{}- Tempo di ritorno a lavoro

{}- Sieroma

{}- Complicanze emorragiche

{}- Lesioni intestinali

{}- Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi

{}- Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi &
\multicolumn{2}{m{14.378cm}|}{\textbf{Risultati: }8 RCT con 526 pazienti, di cui 264 nel gruppo laparoscopico e 253 nel
gruppo open.

{}- \textbf{Recidiva erniaria:} RR = 1.02, 95\% CI 0.41-2.54 (P= 0.97)

{}- \textbf{Durata dell'intervento chirurgico:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità

{}- \textbf{Durata dell'ospedalizzazione:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità

{}- \textbf{Tempo di ritorno a lavoro:} Meta-analisi non eseguit per mancanza di dati

{}- \textbf{Sieroma:} RR = 1.22, 95\% CI 0.38-3.99 (P= 0.74)

{}- \textbf{Complicanze emorragiche:} RR = 0.42, 95\% CI 0.11-1.54 (P= 0.19)

{}- \textbf{Lesioni intestinali: }RR = 1.95, 95\% CI 0.38-9.85 (P= 0.42)

{}- \textbf{Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi: }RR = 0.22, 95\% CI 0.09-0.54 (P= 0.001)

{}- \textbf{Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi}: RR = 0.32, 95\% CI 0.08-1.22 (P= 0.09)}

\\\hline
\end{supertabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
}%
\bigskip
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mention "scrpbook" which I assume is a typo of `scrbook` but the example code you posted uses the `article` documentclass. Please clarify.

Comment: unrelated to hline but you are using a supertabular in a minipage. The only reasonto use supertabular is to allow page breaking but there is never page breaking in a minipage.

Comment: actually it is related to that, just change `supertabular` to `tabular`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually, I just added the `minipage` to be able to rotate the table. The original code had `supertabular` without the `minipage`. However, because I most likely need to rotate those table, your answer solves that part of the question. A few of the tables, however, have the same problem, with `supertubular` but without the `minipage`

Comment: `\rotatebox` can not break over a page either so `longtabular` is unusable in that  with or without minipage

Comment: @leandriis I am sorry: I was not clear. I need to fit those tables in my `scrbook` document, therefore I imported using the libreoffice extension that produced this code. I am still facing the problems with the code, then I will have to move the table in my `scrbook` document, and I imagine I will have several other problems (the format as the first of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a final rule via `\tablelasttail{}` but there is no use in `superatbular` here as `minipage` prevents any page breaking, so using `tabular` solves the problem:

[image]

This doesn't actually fit due to the unusual page size you have specified but I will leave that as it is unrelated to the original question.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=, pdfauthor=, pdfsubject=, pdfkeywords=}
% Text styles
\newcommand\textstyleEmphasis[1]{\textit{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother
% Page layout (geometry)
\setlength\voffset{-1in}
\setlength\hoffset{-1in}
\setlength\topmargin{2cm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{2cm}
\setlength\textheight{17.001cm}
\setlength\textwidth{25.7cm}
\setlength\footskip{0.0cm}
\setlength\headheight{0cm}
\setlength\headsep{0cm}
% Footnote rule
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.119cm}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-0.018cm}\setlength\leftskip{0pt}\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}\noindent\textcolor{black}{\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.018cm}}\vspace*{0.101cm}}
% Pages styles
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ps@Standard{
  \renewcommand\@oddhead{}
  \renewcommand\@evenhead{}
  \renewcommand\@oddfoot{}
  \renewcommand\@evenfoot{}
  \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{Standard}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{2022-01-01}
\begin{document}
\clearpage\setcounter{page}{1}\pagestyle{Standard}

\bigskip

\rotatebox{90}{%
\begin{tabular}{|m{3.6139998cm}|m{7.1060004cm}|m{7.0880003cm}m{7.09cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|m{25.498001cm}|}{\textbf{Studio:} Forbes SS \textit{et al.} Meta-analysis of randomized controlled
trials comparing open and laparoscopic ventral and incisional hernia repair with mesh. British Journal of Surgery
2009.}\\\hline
\textbf{Disegno dello studio}

 \textbf{Livello di evidenza} &
\textbf{Dettagli dello studio/limitazione} &
\multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{\textbf{Caratteristiche dei pazienti}} &
\textbf{Interventi}\\\hline
\textbf{Disegno dello studio:}

Systematic review e meta-analisi di RCTs

~

\textbf{Certezza delle prove:}

Bassa

~
 &
\textbf{Paesi:} Non applicabile

\textbf{Centri:} Non applicabile

\textbf{Setting: }Ernie ventrali primitive e incisionali

\textbf{Finanziamento}: Non riportato

\textbf{Tasso di dropout: }Non applicabile

\textbf{Limitazioni}:

\textbf{Critical appraisal: }AMSTAR II

~
 &
\multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{Pazienti con ernia ventrale primaria o ernia incisionale

~

\textbf{Ricerca bibliografica: }Gennaio 1950 -- Gennaio 2009

~

\textbf{Criteri di inclusione: }Studi prospettici randomizzati comparanti la tecnica laparoscopica con quella open,
entrambe con l'utilizzo di protesi

~

\textbf{Criteri di esclusione:} Studi focalizzati sulla riparazione di ernie inguinali, interventi senza protesi} &
Tecnica di riparazione laparoscopica vs. a cielo aperto con utilizzo di protesi\\\hline
\textbf{Note}: &
\multicolumn{3}{m{21.683998cm}|}{\textbf{Studi inclusi:} Asencio 2008, Barbaros 2007, Carbajo 1999, Misra 2006,
Moreno-Egea 2002, Navarra 2007, Olmi 2007, Pring 2008}\\\hline
\textbf{Outcomes} &
{}- Recidiva erniaria

{}- Durata dell'intervento chirurgico

{}- Durata dell'ospedalizzazione

{}- Tempo di ritorno a lavoro

{}- Sieroma

{}- Complicanze emorragiche

{}- Lesioni intestinali

{}- Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi

{}- Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi &
\multicolumn{2}{m{14.378cm}|}{\textbf{Risultati: }8 RCT con 526 pazienti, di cui 264 nel gruppo laparoscopico e 253 nel
gruppo open.

{}- \textbf{Recidiva erniaria:} RR = 1.02, 95\% CI 0.41-2.54 (P= 0.97)

{}- \textbf{Durata dell'intervento chirurgico:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità

{}- \textbf{Durata dell'ospedalizzazione:} Meta-analisi non eseguita per elevata eterogeneità

{}- \textbf{Tempo di ritorno a lavoro:} Meta-analisi non eseguit per mancanza di dati

{}- \textbf{Sieroma:} RR = 1.22, 95\% CI 0.38-3.99 (P= 0.74)

{}- \textbf{Complicanze emorragiche:} RR = 0.42, 95\% CI 0.11-1.54 (P= 0.19)

{}- \textbf{Lesioni intestinali: }RR = 1.95, 95\% CI 0.38-9.85 (P= 0.42)

{}- \textbf{Infezione di ferita con espianto della protesi: }RR = 0.22, 95\% CI 0.09-0.54 (P= 0.001)

{}- \textbf{Infezione di ferita senza espianto della protesi}: RR = 0.32, 95\% CI 0.08-1.22 (P= 0.09)}

\\\hline
\end{tabular}
}%
\bigskip
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I also would like to discuss about the unusual format. Do you think it would be more appropriate opening a separate question?

Comment: yes ask a new q if it isn't about hline

Comment: can I ask how do you manage to show the output on the forum, as you just did?

Comment: just snip a screenshot of the previewer and then add it to the post (cntrl-G or the image button in the  editor) @FabioCampanile